# Prevent page refresh on cookie banner click

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, cookies, page-refresh

I set up a EU cookie banner: the page refresh when clicked "ok" on a href.

I tryed to use `event.preventDefault();` and: `a href="#" onclick="return false;"` but the link doesn't do his job (allow cookies) and will not disappear.

Can someone help me to prevent page refresh on link click?

My basic html:

```
if (isset($_GET['accept-cookies'])){
setcookie('accept-cookies', time() +31556925);
header('Location: ./');
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
...
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['accept-cookies'])){
?>
        <div class="cookie-banner"> 
            <div class="cookie-container"> 
                we use cookies <a href ="?accept-cookies" id="ok" class="button" > ok, continue </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cookie-banner').slideDown(800);
});

$(document).click(function (event) {            
    $('#ok')[0].click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set cookie ['accept-cookies'] with javascript

Something like this

```
$('.cookie-banner #ok').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var accept_cookies = getCookie('accept-cookies');
    if(accept_cookies === undefined) {
        setCookie('accept-cookies', true, {expires:31556})
    }
})


//get cookie
function getCookie(name) {
  var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
  ));
  return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}

//set cookie
function setCookie(name, value, options) {
  options = options || {};

  var expires = options.expires;

  if (typeof expires == "number" && expires) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires * 1000);
    expires = options.expires = d;
  }
  if (expires && expires.toUTCString) {
    options.expires = expires.toUTCString();
  }

  value = encodeURIComponent(value);

  var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;

  for (var propName in options) {
    updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
    var propValue = options[propName];
    if (propValue !== true) {
      updatedCookie += "=" + propValue;
    }
  }

  document.cookie = updatedCookie;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your code but It doesn't work for me. The page it still reloads itself. I'm trying to handle this with jquery ajax with no succes so far!